# C# - How to fill an existing DataGridView with data from an Access Database

Tags: c#, ms-access, datagridview

I am working on a Tool Crib system. I need to have a way to fill my dataGridView with past Purchase Orders.[PO List on the left side to fill DataGridView](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mw1CK.jpg). I have used this before to fill gridViews:

```
        con.Open();
        OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand();
        cmd.Connection = con;
        string orderNumber = lbOrders.SelectedItem.ToString();
        string query = "SELECT PartNumber from PurchaseOrders WHERE PONumber LIKE '%" + orderNumber + "%' ";
        cmd.CommandText = query;
        //OleDbDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

        OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        da.Fill(dt);
        dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
```

However I don't know how to fill an existing dataGridView table. As in I don't know how to use the columns that I already have to create Purchase Orders. The da.Fill(dt) just adds all new columns and I end up with and extra column and a lot of empty cells.

[Extra Column for PartNumber](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jILsJ.jpg)

I tried to just fill the Item column with this code:

```
        string query = "SELECT PartNumber from PurchaseOrders WHERE PONumber LIKE '%" + orderNumber + "%' ";
        cmd.CommandText = query;
        OleDbDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        //cmd.ExecuteNonQuery(); //not using this code

        //OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd); //not using this code
        //DataTable dt = new DataTable(); //not using this code
        //da.Fill(dt); //not using this code
        //dataGridView1.DataSource = dt; //not using this code

        List<string> result = new List<string>();

        for (int i = 0; i < result.Count - 1; i++)
            while (reader.Read())
        {
            result.Add(reader.GetString(0));
            //dataGridView1.Rows[0].Cells["Item"].Value = (reader["PartNumber"]).ToString(); //not using this code
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < result.Count-1; i++)
        {
            foreach (var item in result)
            {
                dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["Item"].Value = result[i];
            }
        }
        con.Close();
```

This code sort of worked for me. However, it kept saying that my index was out of range and would never fill the "Item" column correctly/completely. The other downside to this is that I still needed to bring in the Quantity. I have the grid bring in the other information when there is a change to a cell value. It looks at the database of items to get description and price, so all I need to do is to be able to fill the Item and quantity columns.

I've been at this for a few hours now and I need help.

Summary: I need a way to fill my Item, and Quantity columns with part numbers and quantities stored in an Access DataBase - DB Columns are [PO#, PartNumber, Quantity]

Sorry if this seems like a lot / not enough information. I just need help.

Comment: Not the answer, but: your code is open to [SQL Injection](http://www.bobby-tables.com)! Please us **parameterized** queries instead of inserting _user input_ directly into your query string!

Comment: yes i realize that and at the moment i don't care.

Also, In the future it would be helpful to actually let the person know how to do that instead of harassing them about it and not letting them know what they did incorrectly.